# Short phrase for "complete tasks quicker"?

Tags: phrase-request

I want to express the following idea in my resume:

> Renowned for constantly looking for opportunity to make tasks complete quicker through automation and refactoring.

As it currently stands, this phrase seems too verbose and doesn't sound very effective. Is there a short phrase I could use to express "complete tasks quicker"?

This might even help me get rid of the "looking for opportunity" part by writing the sentence as:

> Renowned for constantly *X* ing through automation and refactoring.

(where *X* is the word to replace "complete tasks quicker")

Is it possible to rephrase the statement as above?

Comment: I've never heard of you; you're probably not "renowned" for your expeditious task completion. Consider a less hyperbolic statement, even on a resume. Perhaps, "Adept at expediting tasks through automation and refactoring."

Comment: @Todd Uhm, you are right. It wasn't meant to be an exaggeration. I had a misunderstanding about the meaning of renowned. I thought it meant something like 'exceptionally skilled'. I have fixed it now in my resume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer myself after asking a few people offline for ideas and some internet searching. The word is **expedite**. I rephrased the statement to:

> Adept at expediting project tasks through automation and refactoring.

Some other alternatives are: accelerate, hasten.

**Edit**: I had a misunderstanding about the meaning of the word renowned. It is undeniably incorrect to use it in this context, so I replaced it with *adept* as suggested by Todd in the question comment.

Comment: Expedite is the word commonly used in "resumese".

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use improved efficiency" or "increased efficiency":

- **Recognized for constantly identifying and implementing solutions to increase efficiency of the company's manual and automated processes through automation and refactoring.**  For example, I saved the company 50 man hours per month by..."

I personally think that one or two really great examples demonstrated with specific efficiency increase metrics can add great value to a resume.  But then you need to be **even less wordy**, and let your example "tell the story" more than your self-claimed abstract statement.  Something like this:

- **Identified and implemented solutions to increase process efficiency.** For example, I saved the company 50 man hours per month by..."

The more you can let context fill in the blank and reduce your resume to bullet points, the easier it is for the reader to read and understand the value you can provide.  If you're applying for a programming job, it's understood that you "implement solutions" by "automating and/or refactoring".  At hiring stage, they don't  usually care that it happened to be an automation from scratch or a refactoring of code, though your examples help inform.

Note:

- **Efficiency** is a measure of how many resources (time, energy) that a process requires to do it's job.
- **Effectiveness** is a measure of how well a process achieves desired results.

Comment: Agree with everything you have mentioned here. Just to put things in context, this question is concerned with a "summary section" of the resume. I do have the examples with metrics later in the resume. Also, in the field where I am applying (VLSI), automation and refactoring is not expected as much as it is in the software field, so it is indeed something "extra" that I can claim to bring to the table for the employer.